# Setup Castle Windsor in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

I'm trying to setup Castle Windsor for the first time and I'm having some problems with it. I have three projects in my solution:

- Domain
- DAL
- Web

The services are located in DAL. They all inherit from `IService`. (`UserService` implements `IUserService`, `IUserService` implements `IService`). The web application is an MVC 5 application. All Controllers inherit from `BaseController`.

I used [this](http://blog.devdave.com/2013/04/castle-windsor-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html) post to help me setup Windsor but I keep getting the exception:

> An exception of type 'Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException' occurred in Castle.Windsor.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: No component for supporting the service Solution.Web.Controllers.HomeController was found

The strange thing is that the path for the controller is correct.

Below is my code for the configuration:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
  private readonly IKernel kernel;

  public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
  {
    this.kernel = kernel;
  }

  public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
  {
    kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
  }

  protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
  {
    if (controllerType == null)
    {
      throw new HttpException(404, string.Format("The controller for path '{0}' could not be found.", requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path));
    }
    return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
  }
}

public class ControllersInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
          Classes.FromThisAssembly()
          .BasedOn(typeof(BaseController))
          .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}

public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Types.FromAssemblyContaining(typeof(IService).GetType())
            .BasedOn<IService>().WithService.FromInterface()
            .LifestyleTransient()
        );
    }
}
```

And in the Global.asax:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    private static IWindsorContainer container;

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        // Setup Castle.Windsor IOC
        MvcApplication.BootstrapContainer();
    }
    protected void Application_End()
    {
        container.Dispose();
    }

    private static void BootstrapContainer()
    {
        container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());
        container.Install(FromAssembly.Containing(typeof(IService).GetType()));
        var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I made it work. Apperantly the problem was that my services didn't get registered. I changed the ServiceInstaller and the registration in Global.asax.

```
public class ServiceInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(Classes.FromAssemblyContaining<BaseService>()
            .BasedOn(typeof(IService))
            .WithService.AllInterfaces()
            .LifestyleTransient());            
    }
}

private static void BootstrapContainer()
{
    container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Install(new ServiceInstaller());
    container.Install(new ControllersInstaller());

    var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel);
    ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
}
```

Comment: Cool glad it works now.  Did you end up having to change your controller registration at all?

Comment: Nope the registration of the controller was correct. Thanks again for the tips and the explaination!

Answer (score 11):

I'm assuming it's blowing up here:

```
return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
```

What you're asking castle to do here in English is "give me the component that implements a service defined by controllerType".

The problem comes in your registration of your controllers.

```
container.Register(
      Types.FromThisAssembly()
      .BasedOn(typeof(BaseController))
      .WithServices(typeof(BaseController))
      .LifestyleTransient());
```

In this block you are telling castle to register all of your types that implement BaseController and the services they are exposing is also BaseController.

So castle is looking for a component that satisfies the service HomeController and can't find anything because the only service you've got is BaseController.

Long story short, if you remove

```
.WithServices(typeof(BaseController))
```

Castle will assume that each of your controllers is a service and then you can ask for components that implement your controller in the way that you want.

As a separate note, for clarity I'd change Types.FromThisAssembly() to Classes.FromThisAssembly() because you are only looking for classes, not stucts/classes/interfaces, etc that Types will scan for.

Comment: I've made the changes that you suggested but I keep getting the same error. Thank you for the detailed explanation of Castle :)